# Parsing sections of HTML in c#

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I need to parse sections from a string of HTML. For example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>[section=quote]</p>
<p>Mauris at turpis nec dolor bibendum sollicitudin ac quis neque.</p>
<p>[/section]</p>
```

Parsing the quote section should return:

```
<p>Mauris at turpis nec dolor bibendum sollicitudin ac quis neque.</p>
```

Currently I'm using a regular expression to grab the content inside [section=quote]...[/section], but since the sections are entered using a WYSIWYG editor, the section tags themselves get wrapped in a paragraph tag, so the parsed result is:

```
</p>
<p>Mauris at turpis nec dolor bibendum sollicitudin ac quis neque.</p>
<p>
```

The Regular Expression I'm using currently is:

```
\[section=(.+?)\](.+?)\[/section\]
```

And I'm also doing some additional cleanup prior to parsing the sections:

```
protected string CleanHtml(string input) {
    // remove whitespace
    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s*(<[^>]+>)\s*", "$1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    // remove empty p elements
    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"<p\s*/>|<p>\s*</p>", string.Empty);
    return input;
}
```

Can anyone provide a regular expression that would achieve what I am looking for or am I wasting my time trying to do this with Regex? I've seen references to the Html Agility Pack - would this be better for something like this?

[Update]

Thanks to Oscar I have used a combination of the HTML Agility pack and Regex to parse the sections. It still needs a bit of refining but it's nearly there.

```
public void ParseSections(string content)
{
    this.SourceContent = content;
    this.NonSectionedContent = content;

    content = CleanHtml(content);

    if (!sectionRegex.IsMatch(content))
        return;

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(content);

    bool flag = false;
    string sectionName = string.Empty;
    var sectionContent = new StringBuilder();
    var unsectioned = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var n in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")) {               
        if (startSectionRegex.IsMatch(n.InnerText)) { 
            flag = true;
            sectionName = startSectionRegex.Match(n.InnerText).Groups[1].Value.ToLowerInvariant();
            continue;
        }
        if (endSectionRegex.IsMatch(n.InnerText)) {
            flag = false;
            this.Sections.Add(sectionName, sectionContent.ToString());
            sectionContent.Clear();
            continue;
        }

        if (flag)
            sectionContent.Append(n.OuterHtml);
        else
            unsectioned.Append(n.OuterHtml);
    }

    this.NonSectionedContent = unsectioned.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Obligatory link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Parsing html with regex is usually a bad idea, as html is not regular. If you can take a look at a html parser, they are many available, and they will cause far less pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works, using `HtmlAgilityPack` library:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

...

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\file.html");


bool flag = false;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var n in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    switch (n.InnerText)
    {
        case "[section=quote]":
            flag = true;
            continue;
        case "[/section]":
            flag = false;
            break;
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(n.OuterHtml);
    }
}

Console.Write(sb);
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you just want to print
`Mauris at turpis nec dolor bibendum sollicitudin ac quis neque.` without `<p>...</p>`, you can replace `n.OuterHtml` by `n.InnerHtml`.

Of course, you should check if `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")` is `null`.
If you want to load the html from an online source instead of a file, you can do:

```
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();  
var doc = htmlWeb.Load("http://..../page.html");
```

**Edit:**

If `[section=quote]` an `[/section]` could be inside any tag (not always `<p>`), you can replace `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")` by `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*")`.

Comment: Wow thanks. I only just noticed your reply. Let me give it a whirl!

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing

```
<p>[section=quote]</p>
```

with

```
[section=quote]
```

and

```
<p>[/section]</p>
```

with

```
[/section]
```

as part of your cleanup. Then you can use your existing regular expression.

Comment: since the html content is entirely in the hands of the user, I don't actually know what the [section] tags will be wrapped in (could be div, p, anything).